# SQL Select with modified column data

Tags: sql

One database I am pulling from has different locations listed as numbers (2234, 5716, etc). Another has them listed with "LOC." as a prefix (LOC.2234, LOC.5716, etc).

Is there a way to pull the location from the first database, but add "LOC." in front of the location number in the select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a [few](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) [ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) you could do this

```
SELECT 'LOC.' + location FROM Table

SELECT CONCAT('LOC.',location) FROM Table

SELECT CONCAT('L','O','C','.',location) FROM Table
```

If you hit a type error because location is an `int` or something, cast it to a varchar:

```
SELECT 'LOC.' + CONVERT(nvarchar(1000),location) FROM Table
```

Comment: Which dbms? (ANSI SQL way is: 'LOC.' || cast(location as varchar(11))